# I could not make the sidebar button move along the sidebar in HTML,CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello Im trying to create a sidebar for a website of mine that that has open/close button that moves along with it.

I am basing my code this example of [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapse_sidebar) in the example there are two separate buttons for opening and closing. I dont like having two separate buttons for the task and would like to combine them. So i modified the example to this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}


.openbtn {
           font-size: 20px;
          cursor: pointer;
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 50%;
          left: 0;
          background-color: #111;
          color: white;
          padding: 10px 15px;
          border: none;
          z-index: 1;
          transition: 0.5s;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button id="sidebarButton" class="openbtn" onclick="sideButtonClicked()">☰</button>  
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>

<script>

        var lastState = false;
        
                function sideButtonClicked() {
          if(!lastState){
              //open
              lastState=true
              document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
              document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
              document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.left = "250px";
          }
          else{
              //close
              lastState=false
              document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0px";
              document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0px";
              document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.Left = "0px";
          }
          }
</script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

If you try running the code the when you click the button for the first time, the sidebar opens and the button goes along with it. That is great and what i wanted it to do, The problem is when closing the sidebar the button does not go back to its original position. The sidebar opens and close no problem but it would seem that this line of code is not working

```
document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.Left = "0px";
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The name of the style through JavaScript is `left`, not `Left`; does fixing the casing fix your issue?

Comment: You have a typo mistake `document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.Left` should be `document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.left`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although style properties are case-insensitive inside of stylesheets, the JavaScript API for styles is case-sensitive. Therefore, setting `style.Left` won't work since the correct property name is `left`.

```
document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.left = '0';
```

Comment: Yes it works now ! Thank you very much. I should have noticed that, i will be much more careful in the future thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo mistake `document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.Left` should be `document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.left`

```js
var lastState = false;

function sideButtonClicked() {
  if (!lastState) {
    //open
    lastState = true
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.left = "250px";
  } else {
    //close
    lastState = false
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
    document.getElementById("sidebarButton").style.left = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <button id="sidebarButton" class="openbtn" onclick="sideButtonClicked()">☰</button>
  <h2>Collapsed Sidebar</h2>
  <p>Click on the hamburger menu/bar icon to open the sidebar, and push this content to the right.</p>
</div>
```